# how to delete a cell data in a table view and rearranging after clicking the delete button in another view controller

Tags: iphone

hii,

i need delete a cell data in a table view and rearrange after clicking the delete button in another view controller i will go to another view controller on selecting index at row in atable view controller....please do need ful help

Thanks&Regards
Devi.

Answer (score 1):

call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this method with from another class... with editing style set to `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`

provided you have implement the same method in your previous class...

Comment: i do this if have a delete in same view controller but i have delete button in another view controller olease do need ful help

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to your initial view controller with the table to the 2nd controller with you initialize and push it. Then you will be able to call any public methods on that view controller. This will allow you to define a method like `-(void)deleteIt;` and call that directly from the other controller.
Also, if you need to track which cell element was clicked, pass the index along also.

**EDIT**

To pass data to the new view controller, you can do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NextViewController *nvCon = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    nvCon.rootViewCon = self;
    nvCon.selectedIndex = indexPath;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nvCon animated:YES];
    [nvCon release];
}
```

Then call a public method on `rootViewCon` to initiate the delete. You can pretty much just copy the boilerplate code used for deleting table view cells here. There are many references on SO and in the Apple docs.

Comment: thanks alot can u please send me the sample snippet if possible